# Not able to disable Airplane mode on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

My computer's in-built wifi card with a RT3290 chipset stopped working on Ubuntu 15.10 so I bought a usb wifi with a RT2870 chipset, which was working fine out of the box. After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, this has stopped working.

The `rfkill list` command shows that the usb wifi is neither hard-blocked nor soft-blocked.

```
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`
```

In the connection settings, it shows that the Airplane mode is on and it cannot be turned off since it is greyed out.

Any help would be appreciated.

The following is the output of `sudo lshw -class network`.

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 34:23:87:b0:61:1d
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-18-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 memory:c2610000-c261ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 08
       serial: a0:d3:c1:60:0e:98
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=10.109.141.50 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c2504000-c2504fff memory:c2500000-c2503fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:6
       logical name: wlxc83a35ca4110
       serial: c8:3a:35:ca:41:10
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.4.0-18-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Also:

```
dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.274694] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.131418] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    2.595655] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
```

**UPDATE**:

output of

`lsmod | grep -e lap -e wmi`:

```
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** As Ubuntu [16.04 is not officially released yet](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule) you should use launchpad to [file a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so the developers are aware of this and can track it.

Comment: @chili555 I have added the result. Thank you.

Comment: Please also add the result of: `lsmod | grep -e lap -e wmi` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I added the result of this command. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect the issue is the same as here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2320258 See post #6. In the meantime, try the live session for Ubuntu 15.10 and see if the switch now works.

Comment: @chili555 I am not able to access wifi on a live session either now. I have reported a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1569342

Comment: Is there any improvement if you unload the driver for the apparently inoperative internal device? `sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci`

Comment: @chili555 Oh wow, it has started working! I can't believe it. Thank you so much. Could you tell what was stopping it from working?

Comment: Please see my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver for the apparently inoperative internal device may be interfering. Let's unload it and blacklist it. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rt2800pci
echo "blacklist rt2800pci"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Toshiba Satellite 855D with a realtek8188ce using the rtl8192ce driver and wireless went dead with the 16.04 upgrade and I tried everything posted on various forums and still no joy.

What did work was powering off (not just a reset)

Removing the driver from the blacklist

Turn off airplane mode under network settings, then watching the wireless button/switch ...

pressing the FN key with F12 and then the Windows key with F12 (wireless sym) multiple times and stopping once the wireless switch toggles on.

Granted I never touched the F12 key (with wireless icon) and it should not even work under Ubuntu, BUT, it worked for me to turn on wifi when nothing else worked including the blacklist and FSTAB files.